# NTFS file attributes from deleted file applying to new one with the same name

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, ntfs, file-attributes

I created two files at around the same time through Windows Explorer (on Windows Server 2008 R2).

- **a.xlsx** (Created at 16:42)
- **b.xlsx** (Created at 16:42)

I then duplicate **a.xlsx** using copy-paste, to get a third file

- **a - Copy.xlsx** (Created at 16:45)

If I delete the original **a.xlsx** and rename **a - Copy.xlsx** to **a.xlsx**, I can see the created time in Explorer change in front of me from 16:45 to 16:42, the time of the original.

Can anyone tell me whether this is an issue or *design feature* with NTFS, or why it is happening?

Notes:

- I confirmed the same behaviour on a friend's Windows 7 machine.
- I tried doing the same through cygwin bash shell and the created timestamp still jumps back in time. So I expect this isn't Explorer's fault.
- If I just delete the file and replace it with a brand new one of the same name, I also see the time skip backwards to the original. (The created time is show as recent when New > File waits for me to give a name, then old when I name it after the old file.)

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: I see the same thing using Explorer on Windows 7 with NTFS.  Very strange.

Comment: Duplicate of [Wrong date created for files in Windows when copying files, if the file has already existed](https://superuser.com/q/715536/150988). Related: [Unbelievable strange file creation time problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2109152/1672723) (on [SO]).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is by design. If a file is created with the name of a just-deleted file, timestamps, attributes, and security are carried forward.

Reason: Plenty of apps delete and recreate on saving, as opposed to truncating the existing file and writing the new contents. This feature fixes the (for the user unexpected) behaviour that security settings and all that suddenly disappear.

Comment: Unofficial intro: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx; KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190

Answer (score 0):

I independently tested and confirmed this issue on a Windows 7 machine. I then performed the same test on a linux machine and did not receive the same error. The error only occurs on Windows based machines from my test. As Microsoft is the creator of NTFS I cannot say whether it's intentional and either the feature was simply not added to linux based NTFS file systems, or whether it's an actual bug.

My guess is that this is a bug. However it's surprising that if it is it's lasted in the Microsoft platform for so long.

Answer (score 0):

See ["The apocryphal history of file system tunnelling"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923) by Raymond Chen (OldNewThing). Felix Kasza's  comment has a broken URL to this article, which says (excerpted):

> When you use a program to edit an existing file, then save it, you expect the original creation timestamp to be preserved, since you’re editing a file, not creating a new one. But internally, many programs save a file by performing a combination of save, delete, and rename operations (such as the ones listed in the linked article), and without tunneling, the creation time of the file would seem to change even though from the end user’s point of view, no file got created.

"The linked article" is Microsoft KB article 172190,
"Windows NT Contains File System Tunneling Capabilities". 
It has disappeared from microsoft.com; [here is an archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140528165711/https://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=172190).